# React component won't stop fetching data because of setInterval

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I'm using `setInterval` to poll requests and make my app real-time, and I think it might be the culprit why the fetch requests keep coming. This is my React component:

```
export default class ChatBox extends Component<ChatBoxProps, ChatBoxState> {
  interval = setInterval(() => this.fetchComments(), 500)
  state = {
    comments: [],
    content: '',
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.fetchComments(), 500)
    this.scrollToBottom()
  }

  componentDidUpdate () {
    this.scrollToBottom()
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  fetchComments = () => {
    fetchComments().then(comments => {
      this.setState({ comments })
    })
  }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: describe better ``Is there a way to prevent this behavior?`. What you want it to do? make a request when? how much time between requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start two intervals and forget about the first one.

The first will be started on instance initialisation and the second in `componentDidMount()`. But the second will override the reference to the first interval which will then not be removed in `componentWillUnmount()`. You should set your interval only in `componentDidMount()` and init it with `null`:

```
export default class ChatBox extends Component<ChatBoxProps, ChatBoxState> {
    interval = null;

    componentDidMount () {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.fetchComments(), 500);
        /* ... */
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying things. I still have the following dilemma though. Since `this.state.comments` is updated every 1 second, `this.scrollToBottom()` is fired off at the same interval which is problematic for me since the user cannot scroll up.

Comment: @Bargain23 You should generally never unconditionally trigger anything in `componentDidUpdate()`. Either scroll to bottom in the `setState()` callback which you can pass as the second parameter or check for a change of `comments` in `componentDidUpdate()` by comparing `prevProps`, which is the first parameter to `componentDidMount()` with the current props.

Answer (score 3):

You missed this.interval. you have set two intervals. please removed atleast one. you have cleared this.interval not interval.

```
export default class ChatBox extends Component<ChatBoxProps, ChatBoxState> {

  state = {
    comments: [],
    content: '',
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.fetchComments(), 500)
    this.scrollToBottom()
  }

  componentDidUpdate () {
    this.scrollToBottom()
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  fetchComments = () => {
    fetchComments().then(comments => {
      this.setState({ comments })
    })
  }
}
```